# Order of coloured bands of light: red, blue, green, orange, red, violet, green, and violet

Tags: optics, visible-light, diffraction

I am currently studying the textbook *Modern Optical Engineering*, fourth edition, by Warren Smith. Chapter 1 presents the following diagram and explanation when discussion **interference** and **diffraction**:

> If the illuminating source is monochromatic, i.e., emits but a single wavelength of light, the result will be a series of alternating light and dark bands of gradually changing intensity on the screen (assuming that $s$, $A$, and $B$ are slits), and by careful measurement of the geometry of the slits and the separation of the bands, the wavelength of the radiation may be computed. (The distance $AB$ should be less than a millimeter and the distance from the slits to the screen should be to the order of a meter to conduct this experiment.)
>
> [image]

The author then goes on to say the following:

> Now if the light source, instead of being monochromatic, is white and consists of all wavelengths, it can be seen that each wavelength will produce its own array of light and dark bands of its own particular spacing. Under these conditions the center of the screen will be illuminated by all wavelengths and will be white. As we proceed from the center, the first effect perceptible to the eye will be the dark band for blue light which will occur at a point where the other wavelengths are still illuminating the screen. Similarly, the dark band for red light will occur where blue and other wavelengths are illuminating the screen. Thus a series of colored bands is produced, starting with white on the axis and progressing through red, blue, green, orange, red, violet, green, and violet, as the path difference increases. Further from the axis, however, the various light and dark bands from all the visible wavelengths become so “scrambled” that the band structures blend together and disappear.

I'm wondering why the coloured bands appear in the specific order of red, blue, green, orange, red, violet, green, and violet. It seems that it has something to do with wavelength, but I'm not sure. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

This is the single slit pattern in white light, together with the RGB channels of the camera.

The first color next to the central white region appears when the blue channel has its first minimum. But this gives the complementary color of blue, which is yellow. Not red!

Next is the complementary color of green: magenta.

Then the complementary color of red: cyan.

So this has to do with the physiology of the human eye, the three color receptors.

Comment: Yellow? I don't see any yellow in the image?

Comment: @ThePointer, I see yellow. Or, perhaps I should say, I _perceive_ yellow...

Comment: @SolomonSlow Oh, wait: Is this all in the context of the top band?

Comment: @ThePointer, I believe so.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Ok, that makes sense. I was thinking of it in the context of the **four** bands: White, red, green, and blue. For a moment there, I thought I was colourblind (yellow!?).

Comment: @ThePointer I edited a bit, hope that I was clearer now.

Comment: Although, I'm not sure Pieter is correct here. This https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/courses-images-archive-read-only/wp-content/uploads/sites/222/2014/12/20111410/Figure_28_04_01a.jpg image shows a different pattern (magenta, violet, cyan, green, yellow, red) for the first-order rainbow (from https://courses.lumenlearning.com/austincc-physics2/chapter/27-4-multiple-slit-diffraction/). And here's another image: https://s3mn.mnimgs.com/img/shared/discuss_editlive/2191102/2013_10_19_15_10_43/wttsocoz5201143651721492927.png

Comment: @ThePointer That is an interesting link. But that is a schematic. Of a grating. Mine is an experiment that I did with bright sunlight. Of a single slit.

Comment: @Pieter Ahh, ok. Well, I'll just assume that yours is correct. Either way, it doesn't seem that the textbook's ordering is accurate.

Comment: @ThePointer The textbook talks about a double slit. Then it depends a bit on the ration of slit width to slit distance. Veritassium has a nice video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iuv6hY6zsd0

Comment: @Pieter The textbook uses the following formula: $$OP = \dfrac{\Delta \cdot D}{AB}$$ and $$OP(\text{1st dark}) = \dfrac{\pm \lambda D}{2AB}$$ If we assume that (1) the distance from slits to screen $D$ is one meter, (2) the slit separation $AB$ is one-tenth of a millimetre, and (3) that the illumination is red light of wavelength of $0.64 \mu m$, we get $$\dfrac{\pm 10^4 \cdot 0.64 \cdot 10^{-3}}{2} = \pm 3.2mm$$ Thus, the first dark band occurs $3.2mm$ above and below the axis. Similarly, the location of the next light band can be found at $6.4mm$ by setting $\Delta$ equal to one wavelength.

Comment: The textbook then says that, if blue light of wavelength $0.4 \mu m$ were used in the experiment, we would find that the first dark band occurs at $\pm 2 mm$ and the next bright band at $\pm 4 mm$.

Comment: It as only after these calculations that the author says as I wrote in my post: Now if the light source, instead of being monochromatic, is white and consists of all wavelengths, it can be seen that each wavelength will produce its own array of light and dark bands of its own particular spacing. [...]

Comment: [...] Under these conditions the center of the screen will be illuminated by all wavelengths and will be white. As we proceed from the center, the first effect perceptible to the eye will be the dark band for blue light which will occur at a point where the other wavelengths are still illuminating the screen. Similarly, the dark band for red light will occur where blue and other wavelengths are illuminating the screen. Thus a series of colored bands is produced, starting with white on the axis and progressing through red, blue, green, orange, red, ...

Comment: Does this look correct to you?

Comment: @ThePointer The book states that absence of blue produces red, and that is not right. This can also be seen in thin-film interference: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Film_of_soap_interference_3_RGB.jpg

Comment: @Pieter The author could have meant cyan when they said "blue". In the image you posted in your answer, it does seem that the blue-cyan band is filtered out in the red filter, no?